# Flutter related whenever i try to enter text in textfield and the keyboard opens the whole screen goes blank?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=830}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:0.5614035   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=854}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:0.6245614   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=874}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:0.6877193   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=888}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:0.7508772   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=898}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:0.8105263   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=905}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:0.8736842   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=909}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:0.9368421   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=911}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:1.0   /allowWhenFinished:false
I/DEBUG_NAV_InsetsAnimationCtrlImpl(20613): setInsetsAndAlpha-insets:Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=911}   /alpha:1.0   /fraction:1.0   /allowWhenFinished:true
```

How can i remove transparency when keyboard is on?

[image]

Comment: Smells like your widgets are redrawing when they shouldn't.